# Can Automation Anywhere Bots run with locked screen?

Tags: bots, automationanywhere

if a bot is scheduled to run on a certain time, can it run while the windows screen is locked? 
Without unlocking it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the bot can run while the window screen is locked. You can use triggers to do this. There are multiple kinds of triggers supported by Automation Anywhere

1. Email
2. File
3. Window
4. Folder
5. Performance
6. Process
7. Service

Create a New Trigger for Bot and when Trigger, triggers it will run the configured Bot
like.

an Email Trigger runs a bot when new email arrives (need to configure IMAP server details like host, username, )

[image: Bot Trigger Options]

if you want to Auto-login to Computer when Task Run, you can do this with:

go to Tools > Options > Login Settings then

check the box "Auto Login Your Computer when the Task Runs"
[image: Auto Login Cmputer]